# How to move images without moving contact form in revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

Actually i want to keep the contact form on the rev slider stagnant and let the images change at the back. what i mean is right now the form reloads when the slider changes image, i dont want it to happen.

Answer (score 0):

go to static global layers and choose the slider then choose the go to layers and select the import then choose slider add layer that you want not to move press the + button and save and remove that layer from all slides